# How to translate this scala code into java?

Tags: java, scala

I tried to rewrite this following scala code(taken from https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/master/sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/geosparksql/expressions/Functions.scala) in Java, but don't know how to do it for this line:

`val geometry = GeometrySerializer.deserialize(inputExpressions(0).eval(input).asInstanceOf[ArrayData]).`

Could anybody help me? Include Java code I have done so far.

```
     /**
      * Return the convex hull of a Geometry.
      *
      * @param inputExpressions
      */
    case class ST_ConvexHull(inputExpressions: Seq[Expression])
      extends Expression with CodegenFallback {
      override def nullable: Boolean = false

      override def eval(input: InternalRow): Any = {
        assert(inputExpressions.length == 1)
        val geometry = GeometrySerializer.deserialize(inputExpressions(0).eval(input).asInstanceOf[ArrayData])
        new GenericArrayData(GeometrySerializer.serialize(geometry.convexHull()))
      }

      override def dataType: DataType = new GeometryUDT()

      override def children: Seq[Expression] = inputExpressions
    }
```

Here is the Java code I have done so far:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodegenContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodegenFallback;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.ExprCode;
import org.datasyslab.geosparksql.utils.GeometrySerializer;
import org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.UDT.GeometryUDT;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayData;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType;
import scala.collection.Seq;

/**
 *
 * @author Paul Z. Wu Apr 16, 2018
 */
public class ST_ConcaveHull extends Expression implements CodegenFallback {

    Seq<Expression> inputExpressions;

    public ST_ConcaveHull(Seq<Expression> inputExpressions) {
        this.inputExpressions = inputExpressions;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nullable() {
        return false;
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Object eval(InternalRow input) {
        assert (inputExpressions.length() == 1);
        //****** Have trouble here!!!!
        ArrayData ad = inputExpressions.take(0).eval(input.);
        Geometry g = GeometrySerializer.deserialize(ad);
        return new GenericArrayData(GeometrySerializer.serialize(g.convexHull()));
    }

    @Override
    public ExprCode doGenCode(CodegenContext cc, ExprCode ec) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public DataType dataType() {
        return new GeometryUDT();
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Seq<Expression> children() {
        return this.inputExpressions;
    }

    @Override
    public Object productElement(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public int productArity() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

        @Override
        public boolean canEqual(Object o) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    }
```

Comment: What bit of that line do you not understand? What do you think it does?

Comment: @ggovan I'm doing a project in Java and need to implement a similar thing with another type of geometry.  So if this line can be done in Java, I can do it. Not sure why people gave me so much negative score on this? I don't have time/desire to learn Scala.

Comment: I assume the downvotes are for the _seeming_ lack of trying - if if you tried a lot, the post doesn't show it. Perhaps if you share the Java code that you already have, and your best attempt at "translating" this specific line - people will see that you tried, and will have an easier time helping too (because they will have some context to work in, e.g. what Java type you used for `inputExpressions` etc.).

Comment: @TzachZohar  Certainly I have been trying and I did several other translations, but this one got me.  Let me modify the original message to include the java code. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @EJoshuaS  Modify the title...people don't want to help, but want to take challenges ...learnt a lot from mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line can be "translated" to:

```
// val geometry = GeometrySerializer.deserialize(
//  inputExpressions(0)         // get value with index 0 in Seq
//    .eval(input)              // call "eval" method on that value
//    .asInstanceOf[ArrayData]  // cast to ArrayData
//)
ArrayData ad = (ArrayData) inputExpressions.apply(0).eval(input);
Geometry g = GeometrySerializer.deserialize(ad);
```

What's going on here:

- `inputExpressions` is a `scala.collection.Seq`. To get a value by its index `i` from a `xs: Seq`, in Scala we would simply write `xs(i)`, but that's just "syntactic sugar" (i.e. shorthand) for `xs.apply(i)` - "apply" method is special in Scala in the sense that the method name can simply be omitted. So, when moving to Java, we call `apply` explicitly.
- Scala's `x.asInstanceOf[T]` is equivalent to Java's *casting* `(T) x`, in this case - in order to assign the result of `eval` which is an `Object` into a `ArrayData` we have to use casting

Comment: Thanks...as I said, some of Scala code could be easily translated by me. But this piece translation is not for a beginner.  Although feel some humiliated, a day is saved.